# Persist result of aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We try to persist the outcome of a set operation to a separate collection before returning.

```
  Aggregates.project(
                                Projections.fields(
                                Projections.computed("diff", 
                                        Document.parse("{ $setDifference: [{\"local\", \"$global\"] }"))
                                ,Projections.excludeId()
                                )
                        )
                        ,Aggregates.unwind("$diff",new UnwindOptions().preserveNullAndEmptyArrays(true))
                        ,Aggregates.out("globaldata")
```

However,this seems to replace the globaldata collection,instead of appending to it.
Is there a way out in Mongo 3.6($merge is only available 4.2.x)

Answer (score 0):

**Not yet** @IUnknown, but after exploring found that one of the MongoDB dev wrote [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12280?focusedCommentId=1968283&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1968283) that they have implemented new syntax for `$out`

i.e;

```
$out: {
    mode: "replaceCollection" | "replaceDocuments" | "insertDocuments",
    to: "targetCollection",
    uniqueKey: {<set of fields that uniquely identify the document>},
}
```

But after reading on official documentation of MongoDB, I could not find any new update for $out. However, you will see the new `$merge` pipeline which gives the same functionality of appending the documents [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#merge-aggregation).

**In MongoDB 4.2**

```
{ $merge: {
     into: <collection> -or- { db: <db>, coll: <collection> },
     on: <identifier field> -or- [ <identifier field1>, ...],  // Optional
     let: <variables>,                                         // Optional
     whenMatched: <replace|keepExisting|merge|fail|pipeline>,  // Optional
     whenNotMatched: <insert|discard|fail>                     // Optional
} }
```

**So, you better update your version of MongoDB.**